# Domain User Authentication in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: authentication, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm developing an app that will essentially be a kiosk app (I'll use the kiosk features of Windows 8.1 to lock the device down).

So the computer will be always on and always logged into an account with this app running.

However, part of the process is that I need to authenticate users. They'll log in with username and password, choose a couple of things and then click finish which will log them out and take the app back to the login screen.

How can I do this? `System.DirectoryServices` is not available for Windows Store Apps. I was looking at other ways of doing LDAP Authentication and Active Directory Web Services looks promising (and would be supported). But I don't see how I could use it to authenticate (other than the fact that it authenticates he calling user, but I can't seem to get impersonation working there either).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this answer too. I discovered that you have to go to the package.appxmanifest and check off Enterprise Authentication and then you can use CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials in your app to get the username, but not the password.